# Referencing javascript global inside ng-init call using Angular and Django

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I've got a javascript global that is available in my Angular partial:

```
<script>
    console.log(tm.staticUrl);
</script>
```

I don't know how to reference it in the below call:

```
<div ng-init="templateUrl = 'partials/essay.html'">
```

I need to adjust the url based on if we're on a remote server or developing locally, but have no idea how to do this. I've tried variations of this:

```
<div ng-init="templateUrl = tm.staticUrl + 'partials/essay.html'">
```

But feel like I'm misunderstanding how these strings are parsed.

Comment: I believe angular will be looking for a $scope.tm.staticUrl in this case.  Have you tried in your controller assigning your javascript variable tm.staticUrl to a scoped variable and using that scoped variable in your ng-init instead?

Comment: Yes, tm.staticUrl has to be on the $scope for this to work. In general it's best practice to avoid ng-init and assign the value to templateUrl in your controller. See: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4366/files